# Sitecore User Profile Settings not saved when created programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm building a registration component on a Sitecore Site (Sitecore 7.0 ) and while the users are being created, none of the custom profile or role is being created. There are no errors in the logs. The user that is created has the correct user name and domain, but does not have the custom profile and lacks the full name, email address, role and additional custom fields. Has anyone encountered any related difficulties achieving this?

N.b. using email address as username if that will make any difference. I've updated the config to allow this. I've also added some logging underneath, which all outputs the correct information.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
 try
        {
            if (!User.Exists(userEntity.EmailAddress))
            {
                var user = Membership.CreateUser(CreateUserName(userEntity), userEntity.Password,
                    userEntity.EmailAddress);

                User scUser = User.FromName(userEntity.EmailAddress, true);
                if (Role.Exists(Constants.Roles.ExampleRole) && !scUser.IsInRole(Constants.Roles.ExampleRole))
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(userEntity.EmailAddress, Constants.Roles.ExampleRole);
                }

                if (scUser != null)
                {
                    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
                    {
                        scUser.Profile.FullName = userEntity.FirstName + " " + userEntity.LastName;
                        scUser.Profile.ProfileItemId = Constants.CustomUserProfile.ToString();
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.FirstName, userEntity.FirstName);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.LastName, userEntity.LastName);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.EmailAddress, userEntity.EmailAddress);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.TelephoneNumber, userEntity.TelephoneNumber);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.CompanyName, userEntity.CompanyName);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.Sector, userEntity.Sector);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.AddressLine1, userEntity.AddressLine1);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.AddressLine2, userEntity.AddressLine2);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.City, userEntity.City);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.PostCode, userEntity.Postcode);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.State, userEntity.State);
                        scUser.Profile.SetCustomProperty(UserFields.Country, CountryUtility.GetCountryNameById(userEntity.SelectedCountryId));

                        scUser.Profile.Save();

                        result = true;
                    }
                    Membership.UpdateUser(user);

                    Log.Info(scUser.Profile.FullName, new object());
                    Log.Info(scUser.Profile.ProfileItemId, new object());
                    Log.Info(scUser.Profile.GetCustomProperty(UserFields.FirstName), new object());
                    Log.Info(scUser.Profile.GetCustomProperty(UserFields.City), new object());
                    Log.Info(scUser.Profile.GetCustomProperty(UserFields.Country), new object());
                    Log.Info(scUser.IsInRole(Constants.Roles.ExampleRole) ? "true" : "false", new object());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(Nodes.Dictionary.Fields[DictionaryFields.RegistrationForm.UsernameExists].Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message, "RegistrationController");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use the fully qualified user name when loading the user from Sitecore, like this (assuming `extranet` domain):

```cs
User scUser = User.FromName("extranet\\" + userEntity.EmailAddress, true);
```

The reason everything seems to work in your code is because you get a user back from `User.FromName(...)` wether the user actually exists or not.

Comment: This fixed the user's missing custom profile fields, thank you. The user's role was still not being populated - to change this I altered the code to the following after the scUser was initialized:



`Role customUserRole = Role.FromName(Constants.Roles.CustomRole)
scUser.Roles.Add(customUserRole);`

Comment: The thing is that if you don't pass the fully qualified username sitecore always will return you a "junk" user that looks real but doesn't really exist. That's really confusing, the logical thing would be to return a null.